# How do I connect a docker container to multiple ips on the same macvlan network?

Tags: networking, docker

When I attempt to add a second ip address to my docker container in the same macvlan network, using the create, `docker network connect`, start pattern it appears to override the first ip address.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Create a docker macvlan network:

```
docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.100.1/24 \
    -o parent=eth0 pub_net
```

2) Create a docker container from an image, adding an ip address from the subnet to the container:

```
docker create \
    --network pub_net \
    --ip=192.168.100.2 \
    -h mycontainer \
    --name mycontainer \
    -ti \
    alpine \
    /bin/sh
```

3) Add a second ip address with an alias to the container

```
docker network connect \
    --ip 192.168.100.3 \
    --alias mycontainer-int2 \
    pub_net \
    mycontainer
```

(and just to be sure, the result of this command was 0 - success)

```
$ echo $?
0
```

4) Run it and open it to have a look

```
$ docker start mycontainer
mycontainer
$ docker attach mycontainer
/ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth0@if2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:c8:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.3/24 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
/ #
```

And...just to be sure:

```
$ docker network inspect pub_net
[
    {
        "Name": "pub_net",
        "Id": "578df6fd9929b0c44356e32a04043b358c2a052e11377ee7430743cd48566203",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "macvlan",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.100.1/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "7f2fd160b8f7340d75861c1c0f743820ee713b13738a1f09252b0b17da58f111": {
                "Name": "mycontainer",
                "EndpointID": "44af06571b1c6334001cbb13c15702640d93930e30f415052e684a96b0d0a893",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:c8:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.100.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "parent": "eth0"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**How do I correctly add additional IPs (on the same or an additional virtual interface) in the same docker macvlan network to the same docker container?**

Comment: Could you give some background on why you are trying to do this? Checking the [docker's macvlan docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/#dual-stack-ipv4-ipv6-macvlan-bridge-mode) I don't see your use-case/needs covered, and understanding your motivations might help find a solution.

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue There are some cases where it's needed, e.g. SSL but, IME, it's not uncommon to have multiple IPs on an interface. e.g. I do `ip a a 192.168.100.3/24 dev eth0` alot as a SysAdmin.  It's possible that I could break each SSL into a separate container, but that would create unnecessary additional networking.

Comment: You shouldn't be using SSL anymore, only TLS. And it certainly doesn't require a bunch of IP addresses. Again, you really should explain in more detail why you're trying to do this.

Comment: @michael-hampton I don't see what more information is needed to prove that something is going wrong.  If docker can't add the IP address, why allow success?  I've shown that it's normal to add additional IPs to an interface using `ip a a`.  Why would docker think it knows better?  Use cases detract from the question being asked.  I'm not asking "How can you solve this other problem?"  I'm asking "Why is docker doing this?"  If the IP were on a different docker network, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an interim answer to my question.  It *is* possible to do this by making two changes:

1) Add --cap-add=NET_ADMIN to the create command, e.g.

```
docker create \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN
    --network pub_net \
    --ip=192.168.100.2 \
    -h mycontainer \
    --name mycontainer \
    -ti \
    alpine \
    /bin/sh
```

2) Skip step 3 and add the ip address *within* the docker container:

```
$ docker start mycontainer
mycontainer
$ docker attach mycontainer
/ # ip a a 192.168.100.3/24 dev eth0
/ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth0@if2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:c8:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.2/24 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.100.3/24 scope global secondary eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    / #
```

This works, as I can now ping and access the same container via either IP.

However, the caveat is that the IPs must be manually managed.  Only the original IP in the create command shows up in `docker network inspect`

Comment: Thank you, this saved my day! Just one reminder to others, in this case, the IP of 192.168.100.3 must NOT be registered by other machines, even the host machine. Btw, this problem also happened to the default bridge network, I have fired a bug to the docker side: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34571